# Timer who check database and start the function send e-mail

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question about Timer in c# .net application. On my project I need:
Check database record (with date)
If date for example is 15.12.2017 in 14.12.2017 (1 day before date from database) function must send e-mail (email get from database) with information.
I create a function for sending mail but I didn't know how to do timer.
Any ideas ?
I checking few codes with timer but always when I start project the project didnt start (localhost loading loading loading etc etc ...)

Comment: Is your application going to be always running, like a Windows Service?

Comment: What database are you using?  SQL Server can send email and has a scheduler.

Comment: I have SQL server.

Comment: My function must work like a reminder. I sent always same information on email (like a Tommorow u must visit store)

Comment: I am not sure but I'll try. To check dates that are 1 day prior to the date in the database, you'll have to first read the date from the database. Then, there are very easy ways to compare the two dates. Depending on the result of the comparison, we can perform the appropriate action. If you think this approach is okay, then let me know. We can work on the code then.